# Combining multiple research papers with different bibliographies each for a PhD thesis

Tags: bibliographies, thesis, report

I am currently finishing my PhD thesis, so i want to combine my different research papers to a single pdf (i.e. the thesis).

As was recommended in several threads here, I am using `report` as the documentclass. However, when i compile my `main.tex` file and run BibTex afterwards, it happens that only for the first paper the references will show up correctly.

I am aware that somehow comparable questions exist, but the answers are (at least for me) way too detailed/difficult to understand and also are not 100% the same.

All i want is to have a `main.pdf` which comprises several papers `paper1.tex` with `bib1.bib`, `paper2.tex` with `bib2.bib`, and so on.

Here is the code I use.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, notitlepage, openany]{report}
\usepackage{setspace, geometry, subfiles}
\geometry{a4paper, left=25mm, right=25mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm} 
\usepackage[round, sort, comma]{natbib}     
\bibliographystyle{aer}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Preface}
\input{preface.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{paper1}
\subfile{paper1}
\newpage
\chapter{paper2}
\subfile{paper2}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

As for `paper1.tex`, the codes looks like this

```
\documentclass[MAIN.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
here is my first paper with several citations from `bib1.bib`
\newpage
{\normalsize
\bibliography{bib1}}
\end{document}
```

The code looks quite similar for the second paper, i.e. the code for `paper2.tex` is

```
\documentclass[MAIN.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
here is my second paper with several citations from `bib2.bib`
\newpage
{\normalsize
\bibliography{bib2}}
\end{document}
```

However, as explained earlier, the reference will only work for the first paper in my thesis. I can imagine that a proper way to deal with might be complex, but I would deeply appreciate a pragmatic way to solve it (for beginners).

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You either combine all the bibliographies to a singe one at the end of the thesis – in this case you can just reference multiple `bib`-files at once. Or you keep a separate bibliography in each chapter, in this case you'd need something along the `multibib` package.